# How to type annotate a decorator to make it Override-friendly?

Tags: python-3.x, overriding, python-decorators, python-typing, pylance

I find that adding type annotation for a decorator will cause typing error in overriding case in **VSCode Pylance strict mode**. following is a minimal-complete-example (in Python3.8 *or later?*):

```
from datetime import datetime
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any

_persistent_file = open("./persistent.log", "a")

def to_json(obj: Any) -> str:
    ...

def persistent(class_method: ...):
    @wraps(class_method)
    async def _class_method(ref: Any, *args: Any):
        rst = await class_method(ref, *args)
        print(f'{ datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") } { to_json(args) } { to_json(rst) }', file=_persistent_file)
        return rst
    return _class_method

class A:
    async def f(self, x: int):
        return x

class B (A):
    @persistent
    async def f(self, x: int):
        return x + 1
```

Here, `B.f` will be marked as type error in pylance:

```
"f" overrides method of same name in class "A" with incompatible type "_Wrapped[(...), Any, (ref: Any, *args: Any), Coroutine[Any, Any, ...]]"

Pylance (reportIncompatibleMethodOverride)
```

And I find that remove `@wraps` will workaround this issue, but I need it to keep the metadata of the function (e.g. `__name__`).

Hoping for a perfect solution.

Comment: Sounds like Pylance is unhappy you named the first parameter `ref` when you're overriding a method that names that parameter `self`.

Comment: @user2357112 I tried to replace `ref` to `self` and still cannot solve this issue, seems not only this problem.

Comment: Oh, right, forgot the `x` argument. Your override doesn't take `**kwargs`, meaning that `B().f(x=5)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For highly generic instance method decorators, I would typically do something like this: (I hope it is OK that I drastically simplified your example)

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Coroutine
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
S = TypeVar("S")


def decorator(
    class_method: Callable[Concatenate[S, P], Coroutine[Any, Any, R]]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[S, P], Coroutine[Any, Any, R]]:
    @wraps(class_method)
    async def _class_method(self: S, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        rst = await class_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print("...")
        return rst
    return _class_method


class A:
    async def f(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x


class B(A):
    @decorator
    async def f(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x + 1
```

Here `S` represents the instance type (`self`), `R` stands for the return type and `P` for the parameters of the decorated method. With Python `>=3.10` you can import [`Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate) and [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) directly from `typing`.

Note that making the first argument (`self`) to the wrapper method positional-only by placing it *before* a `/` in the parameters is actually important because instance methods obviously bind the instance itself to the first argument, thus not ever allowing `self` to be passed as a keyword argument.

I have not tested this with Python `3.8`, but for `>=3.9` this passes `mypy --strict`, so I would expect it to pass Pyright too.